# Access application object from widget

Tags: android, object

I want to access application object from an widget ( A class extends linearlayout ). I have accessed application object from activity by

```
((mypackage.Applicationname) getApplication()).somemethod();
```

And from Fragment by

```
((mypackage.Applicationname)getActivity().getApplication()).somemethod();
```

Like that how can I access application from a Widget.

Comment: Great Voggella Tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: @sarath I'm not sure what you are doing is a good practice. Maybe if you can explain why you need to do that, a better solution could be provided.

Comment: @BrainCrash..Earlier  I was using a class with static variable and methods to store some data. But now App crashes after holding the app for long time. Because Android garbage collection will clear the static values. So I replace that class with Application class. So I have access from application class methods and variable from activities and some time non activities and widgets..